Why am I getting a this-escape warning from adding `this` to a list?
I don't understand this this-escape warning.  Why is it problematic for me to append this to a list owned by the outer class, in the constructor of (non-final) inner class B?
The warning goes away, in this simple example, if I make the class B final, but I don't think I want it to be final.
/*
  javac -Xlint:all wtf.java

  Produces this warning:
    wtf.java:9: warning: [this-escape] possible 'this' escape before subclass is fully initialized
            A.this.all_my_Bs.add(this);
                                 ^
*/
public class wtf {

  public static class A {

    public class B {
      public B() {
        A.this.all_my_Bs.add(this);
      }
    }

    public java.util.ArrayList<B> all_my_Bs = new java.util.ArrayList<B>();
  }

};


In general, in the constructor of a non-final class, it is not safe to pass this to other methods.
That method will assume what it gets is a fully initialised instance, but when this is an instance of a subclass, it isn't fully initialised in the superclass' constructor.
That method might call non-final methods of this, and this is effectively calling non-final methods in the constructor (since the constructor still hasn't returned), which can be bad. Namely, the subclass implementation might assume that the subclass fields are initialised, when they actually aren't.
In this specific case, you are passing this to ArrayList.add. The above reasoning doesn't really apply because add will not call any methods on this. However, it does store this somewhere that subclasses of B can access, hence escaping this. Suppose in A you declared a subclass:
class C extends B {

    private final String someField;

    public C() {
        // remember there is an implicit super(); call...

        for (B b: A.this.all_my_Bs) {
            // do some processing...
            System.out.println(b.toString());
        }

        // suppose someField is initialised after the loop
        someField = "Something";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + someField.length();
    }
}

When a new instance of C is created, "do some processing" would see an uninitialised instance of C! The constructor of B has added the uninitialised instance of C (aka this) into the list.
someField will still be null at this point, so calling b.toString() would throw an NPE!

You might argue that the compiler should be able to see that there are clearly no subclasses of B. However, subclasses of B can be declared anywhere! e.g.
// this can be put in any file!
class Foo extends wtf.A.B {
    public Foo(wtf.A a) {
        a.super();
    }
}

If you make A or B private, then the compiler will not complain about this, but it also won't say anything even if you wrote the aforementioned C class.

Imagine you have
public class C extends wtf.A.B{
    final Integer foo; 

    public C(Integer x){
        assert x != null;
        foo = x;}

    public String bar() { return foo.toString(); }
}

You don't expect bar to throw NPE, but it can.

How can bar throw NPE? I think you need to add more detailed explanation. I would have thought that for the problem to arise, C needs to access all_my_Bs.

Imagine that List.asd call bar.

Also multithreading.

@k314159 if bar() is called while the instance of C is still being constructed, the constructor may not yet have run (fully). Theoretically possible, in practice very rare (never encountered it in the wild in over 25 years of using Java daily for a living). Mind that this answer isn't in itself relevant to the question as the question was about accessing a potentially uninitialised field from an inner/embedded class, which is an entirely different but tangentially related can of worms.

@jwenting question is about warning and I explained reasoning behind that warning.
